# Visual Studio Team Services - Deploy to local IIS server

Tags: iis, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am currently investigating VSTS for our CI/CD processes and am having a lot of trouble with deploying anything to our on prem webservers (IIS). All of the documentation I've found says to Create a new Deployment group by using the provided powershell script,as admin which I do, but always get the following error message:

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
channel."
At line:1 char:880
+ ... nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Typ ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

[!Full Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d1A6.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d1A6.png)

It feels to me like it's having an issue with downloading the agent,possibly due to the firewall, but our network team have confirmed everything should be alright. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions with what the cause of error message might be?

I have raised a call with Microsoft, but they weren't sure either and suggested I manually download the Agent, which I managed to do successfully and can see an active agent, but that doesn't seem to have any relationship to the Deployment Group and I cant find anything that explains the relationship between Deployment Groups, Deployment Pools, Agent Pools and Agents!

I am really excited to get things working, but this is throwing a spanner in the works - Any help would be gratefully appreciated!!

Comment: Regarding download issue, you can try to download other software through PowerShell with WebClient and check the result (https address).

Answer (score 0):

The deployment agent is the build/release agent too, so you can configure it manually with `--deploymentgroup` parameter.

You can find the detail code in the provided powershell script:

```
.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "{deploy group name}" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://{account}.visualstudio.com/' --projectname '{project name}'
```